# How to inject EJB by parent interface?

Tags: interface, websphere, ejb-3.0, implementation, deployment-descriptor

I`m developing a simple JEE application and tryng to choose @Local interface implementation while buildin the ear.
I have interfaces` hierarchy: `ParentLocal`, `ChildALocal`, `ChildBLocal` and corresponding implementations: `ChildABean`, `ChildBBean`. I can choose the `ChildALocal/ChildBLocal` implementation of `ParentLocal` using annotation. How can I do the same thing using ejb-jar.xml?

**ParentLocal.java**

```
@Local
public interface ParentLocal {
    public String getName();
}
```

**ChildALocal.java**

```
@Local
public interface ChildALocal extends ParentLocal {
}
```

**ChildBLocal.java**

```
@Local
public interface ChildBLocal extends ParentLocal {
}
```

**ChildABean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ChildABean implements ChildALocal {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ChildA";
    }
}
```

**ChildBBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ChildBBean implements ChildBLocal {
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ChildB";
    }
}
```

**ManagerBean.java**

```
@Stateless
public class ManagerBean implements ManagerLocal {
    /**works fine, servlet prints "ChildA", so I would like to get the same result using DD
    @EJB(beanInterface = my.package.model.ChildALocal.class)
    ParentLocal annotatedChildBean;*/

    /**doesn`t work!*/
    @EJB
    ParentLocal childBeanUsingDeploymentDesrciptor;

    //....
}
```

**resources/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar>
    <description>IBM WAS test application </description>
    <display-name>Test Manager</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session>
            <ejb-local-ref>
                <ejb-ref-name>my.package.manager.ManagerBean/childBeanUsingDeploymentDesrciptor</ejb-ref-name>
                <local>my.package.model.ParentLocal</local>
                //doesn`t work
                <!--<local>my.package.model.ChildBLocal</local>--> 
                //doesn`t work
                <ejb-link>ChildBBean</ejb-link> 
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

**resources/META-INF/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <session name="ManagerBean">
        //doesn`t work
        <ejb-ref name="my.package.manager.ManagerBean/childBeanUsingDeploymentDesrciptor" binding-name="ejb/session/ChildBBean"/> 
    </session>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

In WebServlet I inject ManagerBean and call it`s method to print the inner bean name

**MainServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/my_app")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    ManagerLocal elementMngr;
    //...
    String childName = elementMngr.getChildNameUsedDeploymentDescriptor();
}
```

All my child implementations are in the separate modules which I put into the ear.
IBM WebSpehere 8.5.5 shows me the following error when I try to start a servlet:

```
Error 500: javax.ejb.EJBException: The EJB reference in the war-main-servlet.war module of 
the earManager application could not be resolved; nested exception is: 
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface my.package.model.ChildBLocal 
not present in application earManager.
```

**UPD**

```
Error 500: javax.ejb.EJBException: The EJB reference in the war-main-servlet.war module of 
    the earManager application could not be resolved; nested exception is: 
    com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBNotFoundException: EJB with interface my.package.model.ParentLocal
    not present in application earManager.
```

How does the attribute `beanInterface` duplicated in ejb-jar.xml or(and) ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml?

Answer (score 0):

The DD equivalent of `beanInterface` is `<local>` (or `<remote>`) and the equivalent of `beanName` is `<ejb-link>`.

The problem with this example appears to be that the `<session>` element in the `ejb-jar.xml` has nothing to tie it to the specific EJB.  XML elements are considered an override of annotations when the EJB names match.  Since `@Stateless` does not contain a name, the default will be `ManagerBean`, and thus the XML should contain:

```
<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>ManagerBean</ejb-name>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>my.package.manager.ManagerBean/childBeanUsingDeploymentDesrciptor</ejb-ref-name>
                <local>my.package.model.ChildBLocal</local> 
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>

<ejb-name>
```

Or, instead of `<local>` you may use `<ejb-link>ChildBBean</ejb-link>`.

Since all of the beans are in the same application, an `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file is not needed. However, if you do want to use a binding file, the syntax specified here seems correct, so perhaps the `binding-name` value is incorrect.  There would need to be another `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file that configure the `ChildBBean` to be bound to the same location.

Comment: Updated error: I pointed ChildBLocal interface instead of ParentLocal, sory for that. Anyway nothing changed, I removed ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml and now my ejb-jar.xml is:
``<enterprise-beans>
    <session>
        <ejb-name>ManagerBean</ejb-name>
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name>my.package.manager.ManagerBean/childBeanUsingDeploymentDesrciptor</ejb-ref-name>
                <local>my.package.model.ChildBLocal</local> 
                <ejb-link>my.package.children.ChildBBean</ejb-link> 
            </ejb-local-ref>
        </session>
<ejb-name>``
Error is still there

Comment: The `<ejb-link>` is incorrect, it should be the EJB name, not class.  Since @Stateless does not have a name specified, the default is `ChildBBean`, so `<ejb-link>ChildBBean</ejb-link>`

Comment: Use of `<local>` and/or `<ejb-link>` should work as long as the bean is in the same EAR as the servlet. Is it possible they are not packaged this way?  Also, you should confirm the bean is starting... there should be a message like this in the logs:

CNTR0167I: The server is binding the ChildBLocal interface of the ChildBBean enterprise bean in the abc.jar module of the xyx application.  The binding location is: java:global/xyz/abc/ChildBBean!ChildBLocal